# Display results by relevance in keyword search only using Low Search

Tags: low-search, orderby

By default, I want my Low Search results to display with an orderby_sort of last_name|asc:

```
{exp:low_search:results
    collection="my_collection"
    default:orderby_sort="last_name|asc"
}
```

But when a keyword is present, I want the search results to be displayed by relevance.

I tried using a conditional around the orderby_sort parameter above like this:

```
{if low_search_keywords}orderby_sort="low_search_score|asc"{if:else}default:orderby_sort="last_name|asc"{/if}
```

But this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters like that won't work for various parse order reasons. Right now, it's not possible to achieve with just hard-coded params. However, you could use a hidden input field for the `orderby_sort` parameter in the form, and populate it with one or the other using JavaScript, based on whether the keywords field was empty or not.

---

**Edit:** In the latest version, it should be possible to define the sort order like this: `orderby="low_search_score|title" sort="desc|asc"`. When no keywords are given, the results should be ordered by title.

Comment: This does not seem to actually work in practice with the latest EE 2.x version. Tried: `orderby="low_search_score|url_title" sort="desc|asc"`, but Low Search does not then display by search score on a keyword search. It works fine if you remove the url_title orderby parameter, though.